# ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

after updating everything in conda, pip can't install anything

```
conda update -n base conda
conda update --all
```

when install or upgrade anything, this error is show

```
   $ pip install --upgrade HDF5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\main.py", line 45, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder'
```

any help please.
thank you.

Comment: First, try to use Conda to install new packages whenever possible in a Conda environment.  Second, you can try to reinstall PIP via `conda install pip --force-reinstall`.  It may not work, in which case, you should reinstall anaconda

Comment: hello James.
this `conda install pip --force-reinstall` command not fix the problem.

Comment: You will likely need to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda

Comment: Can't reproduce, might be windows only. Also, `HDF5` is not a package on the public PyPI. There is an `h5py`, however (which is an interface to HDF5).

Comment: What is your python version

Comment: @MattMessersmith ok but i have problem in HDF5 `Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***` `Headers are 1.10.2, library is 1.10.1` and i dont know how to fix the problem

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems that [this works](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). Reinstall the latest version of pip:

```sh
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py
```

When you’re done, delete the installation script:

```sh
$ rm get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 10):

Solved this by manually updating: Command Line Tools for XCode.

From the terminal run:
`softwareupdate --list`
which produces a list of available updates.

Wait a bit for a list to display (won't take very long). And look for the "* Label:" under `Software Update found the following new or updated software:`

It should say something like: `* Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-13.0`

Then simply run: `softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools for Xcode-13.0"` and replace the text in the brackets with the Label from the previous output. This will then install the updates and the fix for python3.

Then run: `pip3 --version` and it should work.

Comment: running this, it got stuck at installing and won't let me stop it.

Comment: Can you share the error message? Have you tried restarting your mac and then trying again?

Comment: There was no error message, it just took forever and there is no way to stop it short of killing the process, which seems like a bad idea. It ended up taking 5 hours to update everything with my slow internet

Comment: Ok, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 7):

This happens usually, if you try to reinstall pip and the distro's pre-packaged version mismatches the previously installed version (e.g. `19.0.3 (packaged)` vs `20.0.2 (installed)` at time of writing).

Removing the `/path/to/site-packages/pip*` directories is a simple (yet safe) solution.

Here's a little bash script for the system installed version (thus requires sudo):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

 # Set PY_MAJ and PY_MIN with your own python "major.minor" version
 # Example for python 3.8
 # PY_MAJ='3'
 # PY_MIN='8'
 cd /usr/lib/python${PY_MAJ}.${PY_MIN}/site-packages/ \
 && rm -rf pip/ \
 && rm -rf pip-*/ \
 ; cd -
```

**Note for virtual environments:**
Basically the same is valid for venv's. Only difference is the "site-packages" directory location.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me with the trouble I got in after using sudo with pip :D

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error installing python3 (3.6.9) and pip3 on Alpine 3.7.

In my case the answer was follow the python install/upgrade with:

```
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

The --upgrade option will cause it to uninstall any old versions and install a version compatible with the python version

Answer (score 0):

ok i find que solution and it's fix my problem
 https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7620#issuecomment-576655739

A workaround to get pip working again is getting the [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script and running:
python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1
This will revert pip to the previous version

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how I ended up with this issue, but a combination of previous suggestions and comments worked for me:

1. Remove pip folders from site-packages (for me located at `C:\Users\[username]\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`)
2. Force a reinstall with conda with `conda install pip --force-reinstall`

Hope this may help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that I came across this same error when installing a package outside of a conda env

`pip install thefuck` ([it's a real tool, I swear](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck))

It was defaulting to an old version of pip so the fix was adding a "3"

`pip3 install thefuck`